# How to calculate $\int_0^{\pi}\cos x \exp(-\cos x)d x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there any closed-form expression for the following integral?
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos x \cdot\exp(-\cos x)d x$$
Thanks.

Comment: HINT:  What is a standard integral representation of the modified Bessel function of the first kind and order $1$?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.